# EF Core 2.1.1 Seed method with consturctor call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

Why property setted in constructor of seeding class is equal to 0? I have my own seed method:

```
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int range = 20; // for doubles

        int countOfWorkers = 10;

        modelBuilder.Entity<Farm>().HasData(Farm.GetFarm());

        for (int i = 0; i < countOfWorkers; i++)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasData(
            new Driver
            {
                // i belive that constructor launch in here
                Id = i + 1,
                FarmId = 1,
                FirstName = "name" + i,
                LastName = "lastname" + i,
                UsdPerHour = Math.Round((random.NextDouble() * 20), 2),
                HoursPerDay = random.Next(1, 23),
                DaysOfWork = random.Next(1, 31)
            });
        }
    }
```

`Driver` class have a constructor:

```
public class Driver : Worker
{
    // constructor
    public Driver() => BaseSalary = CountBaseSalary();

    public override double BaseSalary { get; set; }

    //this propertys like UsdPerHours are in my abstract 'Worker' class
    public override double CountBaseSalary() => UsdPerHour* HoursPerDay *DaysOfWork;

}
```

That set value `BaseSalary` based on propertys from Seed like `UsdPerHour`, `DaysOfWork` etc.

From code above, my `BaseSalary` property in database is set to '0', all rows

My question is, is my method`CountBaseSalary` from constructor get call when i starting Seeding my Data? Is it possible somehow run method `CountBaseSalary` after rows that are needed in this method? Where to cast my method to get value that i want to?

Comment: Besides the data seeding, `CountBaseSalary()` inside the constructor will always return `0` because the properties are not initialized yet and have default values (`0`).

Comment: I know, but maybe it is possibilities to call that function in Seed after initializing other propertys without doing `static` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Class`, the `Constructor` is called before `Properties initialize`. So, you should avoid setting properties values from `Constructor` based on other properties.

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < countOfWorkers; i++)
{
    var driver = new Driver
    {
        // i belive that constructor launch in here
        Id = i + 1,
        FirstName = "name" + i,
        LastName = "lastname" + i,
        UsdPerHour = Math.Round((random.NextDouble() * 20), 2),
        HoursPerDay = random.Next(1, 23),
        DaysOfWork = random.Next(1, 31)
    };
    driver.BaseSalary = driver.CountBaseSalary();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>().HasData(driver);
}
```

Comment: Your solution make sense, but when i coded it in the same way as u do, the Salary is still equal to 0

Comment: @michasaucer Do you have the expected value for `UsdPerHour `?

Comment: @michasaucer Try to remove `public override double BaseSalary { get; set; }` from `Driver`